# How to get information on e.g. bonds apart from obscure abbreviations?

Tags: bonds

A fund I'm interested in lists on its [website](https://www.allianzglobalinvestors.de/web/main?action_id=FondsDetails.Eckdaten&l_act_id=FondsDetails&1180=DE0008475054) its top holdings in a format like this:

> UK TSY 2% 2016 2.000% 22.01.2016

My guess is that this is a UK government bond with interest rate 2% and maturity 22.01.2016. But I've no chance to decipher stuff like:

> TSY 0 1/8% 2024 I/L GILT 3MO .125% 22.03.2024

I'm not asking you to translate this for me, but rather for a general method to get detailed information about a bond starting from such abbreviations. At a minimum I would be interested in:

- who exactly issued the bond
- exactly what payments are due at exactly what time
- is the bond traded at some exchange and what's its current price

Surely this kind of information should be available somewhere?! Google doesn't show any results. I guess these bonds are assigned a unique code that would help. But how to get to that code from an abbreviation like above?

Comment: Where did you get these quotes? Isn't there a legend somewhere to describe what each column means?

Comment: @littleadv: I've added a link. I hope it is clear that I don't want to advertise the product.

Comment: Second line is an indexed link gilt 

the DMO http://www.dmo.gov.uk/ should have info on UK Gilts if its just the UK you want information for

Answer (score 1):

You can tell by the name. Thats a UK gilt. Pays 0.125% per annum. Exp 22.03.2024. Inflation linked. Check the DMO website for more info, just as the other poster suggested ... or ask a friend with Bloomberg or Reuters access.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a CUSIP # in the info you posted, but that's the unique identifier every bond should have somewhere on the site you got this from.  With the CUSIP, you can search and receive detailed bond info on any brokerage site (Etrade, schwaab, etc)

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSIP) a CUSIP only applies to North American bonds ... these examples are UK-issued bonds so wouldn't have a CUSIP.